# Choosing between numpy.interp vs scipy.interpolate.interp1d (with kind='linear')

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to choose between `numpy.interp` vs `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` (with `kind='linear'` of course). I realize they have different interfaces but that doesn't matter much to me (I can code around either interface). I'm wondering whether there are other differences I should be aware of. Thanks.

Comment: The results should be identical. You could compare [time tests](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) of the two methods.

Comment: It is guaranteed that the results will be identical for all inputs arrays of x and y values?

Comment: I'm not going to guarantee anything, and there may be machine precision differences, but otherwise I see no reason they would produce different results.

Answer (score 27):

Numpy.interp does not handle complex-valued data or ndim>1, while scipy.interp1d does both.
OTOH, numpy's interpolator is [much faster](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/4903#issuecomment-114259888) (and is likely faster still in more recent numpy version).

Comment: Yes, this is the kind of info I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @ev-br, is calling numpy directly still much faster than calling scipy? I see in the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.2/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py#L492-L591) of scipy 1.5.2 that scipy automatically delegates the interpolation to numpy if some conditions are met.

Answer (score 10):

While numpy returns an array with discrete datapoints, 'interp1d' returns a function. You can use the generated function later in your code as often as you want. Furthermore, you can choose other methods than linear interpoationn

Comment: As noted in my question statement, I know about the different interfaces and I know about methods other than kind='linear', but these aren't the things that I'm asking about.